# Can you use a linked list without the use of class?

Tags: c++, c++11

In my class, I have an assignment with linked lists. However, I feel like there is a lost link when my professor explains it to me. The assignment we have shows linked lists used without classes however with all the examples I have found involves classes. I understand what linked lists are but when it comes to code I am very lost. I have no clue how to make, add data to a node or even add nodes to a linked list! I would appreciate a detailed breakdown of a linked list preferably one without the use of classes, however, if you think it'll be easier in the long run to understand linked lists with classes please explain that version!

Thank you

Comment: Before you start working on linked lists (or just about any sort of dynamic data-structure in C++) you first need to understand *pointers* and *dynamic allocation*. Once you do that the rest should come quite naturally.

Comment: Comprehensive guide [here](https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/a-comprehensive-guide-to-implementation-of-singly-linked-list-using-c_plus_plus-ondlm5azr).

Comment: You really need to be more specific, but I'll try...

Comment: Hey, @einpoklum I just tried to make it clearer!

Comment: The question is in essence "how do I write a linked list?", to which the answer is "read a book, this is way too broad"

Comment: Just a comment; once you've grasped how to write a linked list, throw the code away and never use it again. Instead just use what's already provided for you (and better than what you can hope to write yourself);  [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) - or, in most cases, [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which will out perform `std::list` almost *always*).

Comment: @VictorNwadike: So, I've posted an answer. If it helps, say so, and if you want me to elaborate in some point, ask.

Answer (score 1):

A(n implementation of) a linked list - in C/C++ can be thought of as a bunch of structs which point at other structs. For it to be a proper list, then the first points to the second, the second to the third and so on until the last one which doesn't point anywhere.

For this to be possible the structs need to have a pointer member. Also, since you want to actually put some data in that list, they need a data member.

Ok, that gives us the following (say it's a list of integers):

```
struct node_t {
    int     datum;
    node_t* next;
};
```

If my list has three nodes, `node_1`, `node_2`, `node_3` - in this order, then `node_1.next == &node_2`, `node_2.next == &node_3` and `node_3.next == nullptr`.`

I might also keep a pointer to the first node - the head of the list, because through that I can access all nodes.

Does this help clear things up?